# Unity sprite atlas has strange size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a bunch of images in my project. I assign specific tag to them so that Unity should pack them in concrete atlases. But for whatever reason, I see that instead of making a few 2048x2048 atlases, Unity creates several 512x2048, 1024x2048 atlases. Which is strange, because the default atlas size is 2048. I can't find anything in documetation about this case so I'm asking here.

I should mention that I'm using Unity 5.2.2.

Comment: Which tag do you use to specify a concrete atlas?

Comment: "UI3", specifically. Does it matter? I don't have packing tags inside atlas tag.

Answer (score 0):

In [the unity3d documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpritePacker.html) I found information that

> Default maximum atlas size is 2048x2048.

It specifies the maximum size but it doesn't tell that all atlasses should have this size. It's also mentioned that

> Sprites with the same texture compression settings will be grouped
>   into the same atlas where possible.

There is a way to create your own packing policy:

- Implement the `UnityEditor.Sprites.IPackerPolicy` interface.
- There is an easier way - override the properties (`TagPrefix`, `AllowTightWhenTagged`, `AllowRotationFlipping`) of the `UnityEditor.Sprites.DefaultPackerPolicySample` class.

Comment: "Sprites with the same texture compression settings will be grouped into the same atlas where possible." - exactly why I'm asking this question.